# JSF 2.3 <f:websocket> not working on Wildfly 15.0.0.Final after second deploy

Tags: java, jsf, websocket, xhtml, wildfly

I'm trying to make simple JSF example with usage of  feature to update the content of the page. Unfortunately, it works only after the very first deployment or after rerun of the server.

If I'm trying to redeploy the application all calls to push are ignored and there is no update on web page and in network page of developer tools I see a lot of repeating requests with type *'websocket'* with code *101 Switching Protocol*.

Also, I see this error in server log if I'm trying to stop it

```
11:59:31,444 ERROR [org.jboss.weld.Bean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 100) WELD-000019: Error destroying an instance com.sun.faces.push.WebsocketChannelManager$ViewScope@ff2ea8c of Managed Bean 
[class com.sun.faces.push.WebsocketChannelManager$ViewScope] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

Very likely websockets created by JSF are not destroyed correctly but I can't find out why it's happend.

My named bean code

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bean.class);

    private List<Message> notifications;

    @Inject
    @Push
    private PushContext viewPush;

    @PostConstruct
    public void load() {
        notifications = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Message> getNotifications() {
        logger.info("Get notifications {}", notifications.size());
        return notifications;
    }

    public void sendPush() {
        notifications.add(new Message("!!!"));
        viewPush.send("newMsg");
    }

    public static class Message {

        private String text;

        public Message(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
>

<h:head>
    <title>Primefaces product List</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable id="notifications" value="#{bean.notifications}" var="notification">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Text</f:facet>
                #{notification.text}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>

        <h:commandButton action="#{bean.sendPush}" value="Send push">
            <f:ajax/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <f:websocket channel="viewPush">
            <f:ajax event="newMsg" render="notifications"/>
        </f:websocket>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I have this dependancies in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-jsf</artifactId>
        <version>15.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.SP1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Just tried the same configuration with Omnifaces and it works without any issues. Also interface is very simular http://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket

Comment: Interface is similar since the Mojarra  JSF implementation is based on the Omnifaces one ;-)

Comment: Interface is the same but bugs are different)) I suspect that here is a bug in Mojarra JSF.

Comment: same issue, did you fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. As I mentioned only usage of Omnifaces helped me. If such problems still there let's try to fire a ticket in Mojarra Github.